# Break through Map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I would like to pass these params to server.

[image]

My problem is how can I loop through the map so can get the key and value to pass to server using `http`?

```
var map  = json.decode(obj);
print(map);
```

**Output**

```
{material[0][name]: BRC, material[0][quantity]: 2, material[1][name]: BRC, material[1][quantity]: 11}
```

Comment: You want to send this data to API right? and which data like only value or key value pair?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yeap.

Comment: I think you only need to pass it like in json format with json encode

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede can you elaborate more?

Comment: `material[0][name]` this is your API parameter name right? or anything else?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede ya,my parameter name

Comment: Try with below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = jsonEncode({"material[0][name]": BRC, "material[0][quantity]": 2, "material[1][name]": BRC, "material[1][quantity]": 11, "material[2][name]": BRC, "material[2][quantity]": 11});

var response = await http.post(api_url, body: data, headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json', 
"Content-Type": "application/json"
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do I need to decode it?

Comment: I need to decode it in Map, then need encode it back?

Comment: No not needed  @Tony

Comment: You can direct pass it

Comment: If I need to add this `{"id","1"}` into map, I need decode it first right?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to decode it first because I'm working on same example in that I just passed this encoded data please check this screen shot http://prntscr.com/xtf71u

Comment: server return me data failed to store.

Comment: Remove this line `"Content-Type": "application/json"` and then try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228009/discussion-between-tony-and-shubham-narkhede).